# Yahoo Messenger vs. UAC

Tags: security, windows-vista, uac, yahoo-messenger

Lately I've been needing to play with limiting user rights on some machines, UAC is turned on.  We use Vista, and we also use Yahoo Messenger.  When I use Yahoo Messenger as an Administrator, everything works fine.

However, when I use Yahoo Messenger under a standard user account, nothing happens.  YahooMessenger.exe shows as starting as my user, but no window for me to login or the like.

I've tried to bypass this by having the Task Scheduler start the program as my administrative user at login, but it starts at in Session 0 (and thus not interactive with my desktop).

Any suggestions for allowing the people that use this computer to simply use Yahoo Messenger without giving them administrator access to everything else, as well?

Thanks!

**Update**: I used `cacls` on the Yahoo Messenger folder to give the standard user full control of that folder.  This had no effect.

Comment: "Yahoo Messenger vs. UAC" ... and the winner is? IMHO Yahoo! Messenger is one of the most intrusive IM clients there is, i'm not surprised that UAC goes all berserk. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with giving the limited users read/write/modify rights to the Yahoo Messenger directory on the disk.  If that doesn't fix it, track down Yahoo Messenger in the registry (probably under HKLM --> Software) and give the limited read/write/modify rights for any keys there.

If none of that works, consider switching to something like Pidgin.  I know from personal experience that this will work in a limited environment.

Comment: Updated question.  Also, how do I change the rights on the registry?  And does Pidgin allow me to view webcams, as that's an integral part of this?  Thanks!

Comment: @mrduclaw - no video or voice chat with pidgin.

Comment: @Molly Thanks! How about chanting the registry permissions like he was talking about? :D